# How to ask "Can you hear me?" by phone

Tags: phrase-usage

I need to ask "Can you hear me?" I want know if someone can hear me or not.

How can I say this using other words?

Comment: Mediator, I think there are at least infinite questions that you may ask, in this case, to understand if the person hears what you say, being sufficient that this person answers to the question you posed, whatever it be!

Comment: @Carlo_R. I think the OP isn't sure that "Can you hear me" is grammatically correct/understandable; I made an attempt to answer that. If indeed the request was simply for alternate phrases, you're correct that any number of them could be constructed! :) I think the simplest should suffice in most cases though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think another way to say this is necessary; "Can you hear me?" is perfectly understandable and common when speaking on the phone. No other phrase comes to mind; this is a simple and clear way of saying exactly what you mean, and it is what I would say if I were dealing with a finicky phone connection.

A slight variation on the phrase, "Can you hear me now?" (used when you've moved into a quieter room, perhaps, or done something else you hope will improve the listener's ability to hear you) was made into a series of [Verizon commercials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPwPo-IAQ-E) several years ago.

Comment: Is *"Do you hear me?"* correct, too?